# How to move tab title from top to bottom in gnome-terminal on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I do love konsole on redhat, but now I have to work with Ubuntu.

So I installed konsole on Ubuntu, but it seems not good since when I copy something by selecting, tail of the line are full filled with blank space. Too ugly!

Although gnome-terminal doesn't have such problem, all tab names are placed on the top of screen, it's not convenient too when I use it (eyes always on bottom of screen, I have to move my eyesight from bottom to top and reverse).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's been over a decade, but this is one of the first Google hits, and it has no answer! Shamelessly stolen from [ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/673249/139131):

---

Move to top:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position top
```

Move to bottom:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Settings tab-position bottom
```

---

Confirmed this worked today on a RHEL8 box. Now I just need to fix my clipboard problems between `gnome-terminal` and everything else under KDE...